# take a snapshop of a qgraphicsview

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I am using Qt 4.5 and a qgraphicsscene/view to show video to the user.
I would like to provide a "take a snapshop" button and I am sure that there is a pretty straightforward way much simpler of everything I am thinking about.
How can I do this elegantly?

BTW, the code is here : 
http://gitorious.org/handy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the method [`QWidget::grab()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab). This method renders the given widget to a pixmap and returns that pixmap. Then you can do whatever you like with that, like saving to a file using [`QPixmap::save()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save).

Answer (score 2):

See [`QScreen::grabWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow) and [`QWidget::grab()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab).

With `grabWindow` you can even capture a window outside of your application, e.g. the screenshot example program:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html